# Bootstrap modal dialog - show table with one cell fully transparent

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I need to display table in bootstrap modal dialog, and I want one column to be 
fully transparent - to contain check-box element. That column header should also be transparent.

transparent-column-without-header:

[image: http://imgur.com/af3BOD9]

Comment: Please show your markup instead of an image. This is a code and programming Q&A site :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that checkbox is the last column of the table, it's pretty easy with pseudo-elements. I don't know how you are styling you table exactly, but this should help (it's written in sass / less syntax):

```
tr {
  border: 0;
}

tr th {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #333;

    &:last-child {
      background: transparent;
      border: 0;
  }
}

tr td {
  background: #eee;

  &:last-child {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
  }
}

tr:nth-child(2n) td {
  background:  #f3f3f3;

    &:last-child {
    background: transparent;
  }
}

tr:hover {

  td {
    background: #999;

    &:last-child {
      background: transparent;
    }
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b5y7huky/1/

I use pseudo-elements to make last column transparent and to remove border. 
Note, that if you set background on tr, but not on td, it won't work.